# JPA merge not working as expected

Tags: jpa, openjpa

I am trying to implement transaction management in EJB application with Openjpa as ORM tool.

I am trying to implement a scenario where if a db update operation fails for an entity, then db operations for all other entities in same transaction
also rollback. So I have an entity A and I explicitly set one of it's non-nullable field to null and call `entitymanager.merge()` method for this entity.I expect that due to non-nullable constraint db operation would fail and `PersistenceException` would be thrown. But nothing of that sort happens, though A's state is also not persisted.
But if I first call `find()` using A's id and then call `merge()`, I get exception.

I used to think that `merge()` alone is sufficient to take care of all. Why do I need to explicitly call `find()` before merge?

Comment: perhaps, show some code. show the code of calling find() prior to calling merge(), and another code that's not calling find().

Answer (score 0):

Changes are not required to be synchronized to the database until you call em.flush(), or commit the associated transaction.